# How to check payment method on a WooCommerce order by id?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-method

I want to make some changes if the chosen payment method is COD. On existing WC_Order i have used

```
($order->payment_method_title == 'Cash On Delivery' ? ... : ... );
```

to retrieve the title.
But i would like to check against the id (cod) because the title string gets translated to different languages which doesn't make it a good solution.

Is there a way to retrieve the id on a WC_Order in woocommerce?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The post meta key for the payment method ID is simply `_payment_method`

So if `$order->payment_method` doesn't have the magic methods in place to get that automatically, you could retrieve the post meta using traditional WordPress

```
get_post_meta( $order->id, '_payment_method', true );
```

**Update for WooCommerce 3.0**

```
$order->get_payment_method();
```

Comment: Good to hear. Don't forget to mark the this as the answer by clicking on the checkbox next to it.

Comment: @helgatheviking can I get credit card info entered by customer on thankyou page?

Comment: Please search the site to see if that has already been asked and if not, try asking your own question.

Comment: the correct function of order class is get_payment_method() so use $order->get_payment_method();  better approach then using the old post_meta function

Comment: Agreed, this answer is from 2014 so it's outdated now.

Answer (score 9):

If you want the title of the payment method you can do:

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$payment_title = $order->get_payment_method_title();
```

This returns the string set in the Woocommerce > Payment methods, ex: `Paypal`.

Here are some very helpful references and documentation that will help you do anything you want with WooCommerce.

- [WooCommerce Order Class](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Order.html#method_get_payment_method_title)
- [WooCommerce Reference Docs](https://developer.woocommerce.com/)

Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

If you need the payment gateway object itself you can use the `wc_get_payment_gateway_by_order` function.

```
$payment_gateway = wc_get_payment_gateway_by_order( $order );
```