# Get the payment methods history from WooCommerce customers

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, payment-method

I've [found a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26011837/how-to-check-payment-method-on-a-woocommerce-order-by-id/56723062#56723062) that should help me get the information that I'm after: the payment method(s) that customers have used historically in their orders.

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$payment_title = $order->get_payment_method_title();`
```

Unfortunately, I'm not sure where to begin with this information. What would I post that string into to have it perform my expected output?

I would like to export this into a .csv file so I can import into a spreadsheet.

Everything I find so far seems to think I already know where to begin. I'm just looking for a simple pointer on where to start.

Comment: We don't know where / when you want to get this data...

Comment: I would love to get this data into a .csv file. And I'd love to get it now. I'll edit my post to clarify.

Comment: Yes, but I meant where/when in the flow of your application? Or you are trying to get this out as a one-off report, or what?

Answer (score 1):

To get the payment gateways historic by customer you need:

- First to get customers
- to get the orders for each customer
- to display the payment list for those orders

Try the following:

```php
// Get customers IDs
$customers_ids = get_users( array(
    'role__in' => array('customer'),
    'number' => 10,  // First 10 customers
    // 'offset' => 0,
) );
echo '<pre>'. print_r( count($customers_ids), true ) . '</pre>';

// Loop through customers
foreach ( $customers_ids as $user ) {

    echo '<div class="customer">
    <p class="user-id"><strong>User ID:</strong> '.$user->ID.' - <strong>User email:</strong> '.$user->user_email.'</p>';

    // Get Customer paid orders
    $customer_orders = wc_get_orders( array(
        'limit'         => -1,
        'customer'      => $user->ID,
        'status'        => wc_get_is_paid_statuses(),
    ) );

    echo '<ul class="payment-title">';

    // Loop through orders
    foreach( $customer_orders as $order ) {
        printf('<li><strong>Order:</strong> #%s - <strong>Date:</strong> %s - <strong>Payment:</strong> %s</li>', 
            $order->get_id(), 
            $order->get_date_created()->format('Y-m-d'), 
            $order->get_payment_method_title()
        );
    }
    echo '</ul></div>';
}
```